# Windows Authentication in a WCF service hosted in Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, wcf, authentication

I have a WCF service hosted in an Azure Web App.  I turned on Azure Active Directory.  My binding is set up as so:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2048000">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="65536"/>
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

This should cause it to prompt for a user name and password.  Instead I get :

> The authentication schemes configured on the host ('Anonymous') do not allow those configured on the binding 'BasicHttpBinding' ('Negotiate').  Please ensure that the SecurityMode is set to Transport or TransportCredentialOnly.  Additionally, this may be resolved by changing the authentication schemes for this application through the IIS management tool, through the ServiceHost.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemes property, in the application configuration file at the  element, by updating the ClientCredentialType property on the binding, or by adjusting the AuthenticationScheme property on the HttpTransportBindingElement.

Other than enabling Azure Active Directory, I don't see another way to disable anonymous logins.  Does anyone know how to disable anonymous in Azure App Services?

Comment: The one way is building authentication in you app itself. This should be done by yourself. But I still want to make clear, if you enabled AAD authentication for your app or other identity providers, you needn't build it in your app. It should be done by Azure portal and work well.Refer to this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication

Comment: So is WCF not the way to go with this?  It seems they have something new that uses Entity Framework.